# jQuery div show on hover with some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation with two div's and some UL inside it. I want to have the second column hidden and make it to appear only on hover. Moreover it should display only UL which attribute "data-category-id" is the same as "data-parent-category-id". For some reason that is beyond my power I need to make this using jQuery. Some smooth animation would be nice as well.

Here is a code I already created, but it obviously has some issues. For some reason When I mouseenter element that should make the second column appear it keeps showing and hiding.

```
    const itemLevelOne = $('.cs-navigation__item--level_1');
    const itemLevelTwo = $('.cs-navigation__item--level_2');
    const menuLevelThree = $('.cs-navigation__column___third');

    itemLevelTwo.hide();
    menuLevelThree.hide();
    itemLevelOne.mouseenter(function () {
        var attr = $(this).attr('data-category-id');
        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
            itemLevelTwo.each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr('data-parent-category-id') === attr) {
                    $(this).show('200');
                    menuLevelThree.show('200');
                } else {
                    $(this).hide('200');
                    menuLevelThree.hide('200');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I also created a codepen with some HTML code for so it is quite similar to what i have on my website. The second column should appear only when you HOVER on "El Hover" and "El Hover 2". In any other scenario it should be hidden.

https://codepen.io/bordini/pen/GRXgNEo

Hope there is some good soul that will be able to help me resolve this issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have the `<UL>` of level 2 encapsulated in a `<DIV>` with class `cs-navigation__column___third` (HTML line 24) so it's part of your `menuLevelThree`. The `menuLevelThree` you keep `show()` and `hide()` - ing in the event handler for each item of level two which is why the entire level two menu is flickering.

Maybe you misplaced the level 3 DIV?

I commented out your `menuLevelThree` manipulation in the event handler and changed the first call to `.show()` to make it visible initially and now level 2 menu shows. Now you need to also implement an `mouseleave` event handler to hide the level 2 menu.

Oh, and if you are open to using jQuery-UI you may want to consider the https://jqueryui.com/menu/ widget - then you don't need to manually handle the showing and hiding of menu items. However I think you'll need to construct your menu structure hierarchically (level 2 is child of top level and level 3 is child of one particular level 2).

```js
const itemLevelOne = $('.cs-navigation__item--level_1');
        const itemLevelTwo = $('.cs-navigation__item--level_2');
        const menuLevelThree = $('.cs-navigation__column___third');

        itemLevelTwo.hide();
        menuLevelThree.show();  // change to show()
        itemLevelOne.mouseenter(function () {
            var attr = $(this).attr('data-category-id');
            if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
                itemLevelTwo.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).attr('data-parent-category-id') === attr) {
                        $(this).show('200');
                        // menuLevelThree.show('200');
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide('200');
                        //menuLevelThree.hide('200');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

.cs-navigation__column___second{
  background: red;
}
.cs-navigation__column___third{
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="cs-navigation__column cs-navigation__column___second cs-navigation__extras" style="width: 291.16px;">
    <ul class="cs-navigation__list cs-navigation__list--level_1" data-parent-item-id="7" style="column-count: 1; width: 150px;">
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_1">
        <a href="#">El 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_1">
        <a href="#">El 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_1" data-category-id="57">
        <a href="#" class="cs-navigation__link cs-navigation__link--level_1">
          El Hover</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_1" data-category-id="60">
        <a href="#" class="cs-navigation__link cs-navigation__link--level_1">
          El Hover 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_1">
        <a href="#">El 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="cs-navigation__column cs-navigation__column___third cs-navigation__extras" style="width: 150px;">
    <ul class="cs-navigation__list cs-navigation__list--level_2" data-parent-item-id="57">
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_2" data-category-id="32" data-parent-category-id="57">
        <a href="#" class="cs-navigation__link cs-navigation__link--level_1">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_2" data-category-id="32" data-parent-category-id="57">
        <a href="#" class="cs-navigation__link cs-navigation__link--level_1">2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_2" data-category-id="32" data-parent-category-id="57">
        <a href="#" class="cs-navigation__link cs-navigation__link--level_1">3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="cs-navigation__list cs-navigation__list--level_2" data-parent-item-id="60">
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_2" data-category-id="34" data-parent-category-id="60">
        <a href="#" class="cs-navigation__link cs-navigation__link--level_1">1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cs-navigation__item cs-navigation__item--level_2" data-category-id="34" data-parent-category-id="60">
        <a href="#" class="cs-navigation__link cs-navigation__link--level_1">2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```